# Don't quite get the type='module' property for importing script in html

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I read through quite a number of forums and discussions online, also some explanation regarding module in javascript and kind of understand what they do, but I still can't really get this error.

I have a function created in my main.js

```
function display(value){
}
```

and I'm calling it from my HTML input

```
<input id="test"... onchange="display(true)">

<script src="./js/main.js" async></script>
```

That function works perfectly fine. However, when I change my javascript type="module" as below, it suddenly throws an error saying that the display() is not defined.

```
<script type="module" src="./js/main.js" async></script>
```

I am thinking this might be due to my display function that is a local function rather than a global one? 
How do I change it to be global? I tried to look online but it seems like there are only ways to define a global variable but not a global function? Or can I not do that?

Comment: Have you tried to export the function?

Comment: @julianobrasil Yeap, I tried to do "export function display...." but it wouldn't work either. It still can't find the function.

Comment: But really you should just avoid attaching events from HTML attributes. Globals are prone to break your code, + event-attributes have very weird rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module is runned in a different context, so It can not inherit variables whether global or local.

And AFAIK the only reason you could add `type=module` to your script is to use Import\Export Statements so I think there is no reason to do that.

If you want to load the script asynchronously, you could add the `defer` attribute instead, It works more or less in the same way.

The new code will look like:

```
<script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I am trying to use the export and import statements in javascript. If I wanted to use that, isn't it necessary to add type=module?

Comment: Yes, If you want to use import/export, you need to specify `type=module` but if you want any variable to be used outside that module(script), you'll have to set that value to window explicityl, like: `window.display = function(value) {...}`